# MySQL won't insert text, only numbers

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I am trying to insert values from $_POST into a MySQL table, and if I input numbers into the form, it works fine. However, whenever I type text, I get a message like "unknown column 'exampleinput' in 'field list'". I am a pretty amateur coder, so I may be missing something basic. Mysql fields are already set to VARCHAR. My code looks like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users2
            (username, primaryemail, password) VALUES($username, $newEmail, $newPassword)")
            or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add quotes around your input if you want to insert text into your table:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users2 (username, primaryemail, password)
            VALUES('$username', '$newEmail', '$newPassword')");
```

You should also consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) to perform your queries on your database as `mysql_*()` functions are now deprecated.

Comment: You could also use PDO [Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)